# How do I use custom events in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How do I use custom events in TypeScript?

In jQuery I do this:

```
$("#btnShowExplorer").click(function () {
            $.event.trigger("showexplorerpf");
        });
```

and somewhere else I 'listen' for that event

```
        // bind to the special custom event
        $('#idExplorerWindow').bind("showexplorerpf", function () {

            // do stuff...

        });
```

I am now moving my code to TypeScript - I have a ref to the jQuery type [def file](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts) but the $.event.trigger is not recognized..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to extend the jQuery interface. My example has it all in one file, but it doesn't have to be in the same file - just one you reference.

```
interface JQueryEvent {
    trigger(name: string): void;
}

interface JQueryStatic {
    event: JQueryEvent;
}

$("#btnShowExplorer").click(function () {
    $.event.trigger("showexplorerpf");
});
```

Comment: It adds type information so TypeScript understands what is possible with jQuery. They are called type definitions. So the static checking that TypeScript gives you can be extended to cover plain JavaScript using this method.

Comment: Better yet, if you figure out that the JQuery type definitions you're using don't support something that JQuery does, fix it, and then submit a pull request to DefinitelyTyped: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped. (You *are* using the DefinitelyTyped definitions, right?)

Comment: Definitely Typed is step 1 and step 5 of my process: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201301/Blog/Complex-TypeScript-Definitions-Made-Easy/

Answer (score 0):

Actually **trigger()** has multiple signatures.

Check  http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

For me this works better as I need to send some data with event:

```
interface JQueryEvent {
    trigger(name: string, data:any[]): void;
}

interface JQueryStatic {
    event: JQueryEvent;
}
```

Comment: Would have been nice to show how it is used . The API reference is good , just would have preferred an example of usage . Like my property changed .. trigger..